# Illustrator - Making inside of image transparent

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

I'm trying to make the inside parts of an image transparent. I used the image trace feature in Illustrator 6 to successfully get the outside transparent, but when I attempt to select the inside parts (inside the hand, around the eye) and then delete, it goes to black instead of transparent. See image below for details, I basically would like all whitespace transparent (so its just an outline)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Illustrator 6? are you on Silicon Graphics workstation too? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make the *Image Trace*, open up the *Image Trace Panel*, Show the *Advanced* section and check the *Ignore White* checkbox. This should make Illustrator ignore the white areas, making them holes in the black shapes instead.

If you don't want to make the trace again, you can subtract the white parts from the black parts using the *Minus Front* button in the *Pathfinder Panel*, when you have two shapes selected.

Answer (score 2):

Trace the image.

Open the **Image Trace Panel**.

Check **Ignore white**.
This will erase the white and keep its space blank.

Image below:

[image]

Comment: I did not see the other answer untill I submit mine. But I will keep it because the image.

Comment: Must have ... reputation ... points ... :-)

Comment: @LeoNas it happens when your typing a answer then your in sort of a update limbo

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done ignore white... (it's too late for whatever reason) you can use pathfinder divide to separate (divide) all the objects and then delete the white parts. An easy way to delete all of the white parts is to go into isolate mode (double click on group, or from the right click menu), then use the magic wand tool to select the white fill objects. (or the select > same fill)